# codename one ios.includePush keeps resetting to false in netbeans.

Tags: ios, netbeans, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, codenameone

I created a push notification development certificate for IOS and saved the p12 file and added it to my server. I then generated new ios certificates in codename one. Whenever I set my ios.includePush to true in Build Hints. It always resets to false when I go back in. I looked for the "special UI" in Properties -> IOS -> Options however there is nothing about push notifications in that tab. I do have a Pro account. What am I doing wrong? Why can't the build hint be set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some build hints conflict with GUI settings that are available via
>   custom UI. E.g. the iOS section in the preferences has an Include Push
>   checkbox that conflicts with `ios.includePush` this can result in build
>   hints that are ignored! Make sure you use the UI elements when they
>   are available!

From the [Codename One Developer Guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

You need to check the flag here:

[image: UI to check]

Notice that in the new IntelliJ/IDEA plugin we took [a new approach for settings](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/a-new-idea.html) that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: When I go into IOS -> Options the checkbox for "Include push" is disabled so I cannot check it. But I do have a pro account.

Comment: Press the login button in the main ui